# Cannot use malloc in Contiki

Tags: c, cross-compiling, iot, contiki, contiki-ng

I am trying to write a simple program using the Contiki-ng operating system for IoT platforms. First tests were ok, but something weird happens when trying to allocate dynamic memory. The test code I'm using is the following:

```
#include "contiki.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

PROCESS(main_process, "main_process");

AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&main_process);

PROCESS_THREAD(main_process, ev, data) {
    uint8_t *nonce;
    int i;

    PROCESS_BEGIN();

    nonce = (uint8_t *) malloc(32 * sizeof(uint8_t));
    if (nonce != NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            nonce[i] = 0;

        printf("Todo OK\n");
    } else {
        printf("Todo mal\n");
    }

    PROCESS_END();
}
```

When building the project, an error rises stating that "**In funtion _sbrk_r: undefined reference to _sbrk**". After looking some forums on internet, I managed to solve this problem by including the following line into the Makefile of the project:

```
MODULES += os/lib/newlib
```

This solves the problem because inside the path os/lib/newlib there is a file, syscalls.c, which implements the mentioned _sbrk function. However, the following error rises now:

[image]

I have not found anyone over the internet with the same problem, so I got stuck here. Additionally, I don't know why but since then, removing the line "MODULES += os/lib/newlib" from the Makefile does nothing, and the problem with _eheap and _heap persists without returning to the undefined _sbrk error. However, I believe that this weird error is due to something wrong with Eclipse IDE cleaning the project. The code from syscalls.c, if needed, is the following:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#define DEBUG 0
#if DEBUG
#define PRINTF(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define PRINTF(...)
#endif
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/**
 * \brief Enlarges the allocated heap space
 * \param incr Number of bytes by which to increase the heap space
 * \return The previous end of heap on success (which is also a pointer to the
 *         start of the newly allocated memory if \p incr is positive), or
 *         <tt>(caddr_t)-1</tt> with \c errno set to \c ENOMEM on error
 */
caddr_t
_sbrk(int incr)
{
  /*
   * Newlib's _sbrk_r() assumes that this global errno variable is used here,
   * which is different from the errno definition provided by <errno.h>.
   */
#undef errno
  extern int errno;

  /* Heap boundaries from linker script. */
  extern uint8_t _heap;
  extern uint8_t _eheap;

  static uint8_t *heap_end = &_heap;
  uint8_t *prev_heap_end = heap_end;

  if(heap_end + incr > &_eheap) {
    PRINTF("Out of heap space!\n");
    errno = ENOMEM;
    return (caddr_t)-1;
  }

  heap_end += incr;
  return (caddr_t)prev_heap_end;
}
```

I hope someone could help me. I have read that Contiki gives more ways of using dynamic memory, but I need to do it this way because other parts of the code rely on the use of malloc and cannot be changed.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason you want to do dynamic allocation, instead of using e.g. an array? Especially considering that your current example have hard-coded the magic number `32` in the allocation and the initialization.

Comment: Your CRT seems to assume Linux. What's an "IoT" platform more specifically? Can it be a bare metal microcontroller one or is it always a Linux PC in disguise?

Comment: As for the problem with the `_heap`, it seems you need to configure your own "heap", an area of memory dedicated for it. It should probably be documented somewhere.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This was just a simple test code for the malloc function. The reason is that the whole project depends on a library written in C that is the one performing dynamic allocations inside, so there is no way of rewriting that

Comment: @Lundin Exactly, the application is being cross-compiled to run on an bare metal microcontroller on an external board.

Comment: @Jaime_mc2 Then you should forget all about using hosted system libraries, including heap allocation. The vast majority of microcontroller systems don't allow heap allocation since it doesn't make any sense there.

Answer (score 1):

The short is that you almost certainly don't need and don't want to use `malloc()` on a Contiki-NG microcontroller. Use Contiki's [memb module](https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/wiki/Documentation:-Memory-management) instead.

The long answer is that you can add the `_heap` symbol by using a linker script. Check example linker scripts provided by Contiki-NG on how to do that. For example, the script `arch/cpu/cc26x0-cc13x0/cc26xx.ld` (for the cc26x0-cc13x0 platform) places `_heap` immediately after the BSS segment:

```
.bss :
{
    /* ... */
} > SRAM

_end = .;  /* End of the .bss segment. */
/* ... */
_stack = .;
_heap = _stack;
```